# How do i get the text on marker when i click on it?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have added the text to the marker using marker options

```
 TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(" "+assetName+" ");
    text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
    IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(context);
    generator.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    generator.setContentView(text);
    generator.setRotation(360);
    Bitmap icon = generator.makeIcon();

    MarkerOptions tp = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
    MapFragment.googleMap.addMarker(tp);
```

Now i want the text "iqbal" on the marker when i click on it.

[image]

Comment: Your question is still unclear and lacks a premise

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I am using  MarkerOptions.In this link they are directly adding the marker

Comment: @RituSumanMohanty than change your question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the text from the marker because your text is inside a generated bitmap. However, you can save the text and anything you can need in the marker [tag](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)):

```
 TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(" "+assetName+" ");
    text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
    IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(context);
    generator.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    generator.setContentView(text);
    generator.setRotation(360);
    Bitmap icon = generator.makeIcon();

    MarkerOptions tp = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon))
                             .tag(text);
    Marker marker = MapFragment.googleMap.addMarker(tp);
```

And then

```
String text = marker.getTag().toString()
```

Comment: Yes. I agree with @Mariano Córdoba's answer

Answer (score 1):

Marker options doesnt have tag attribute. So you have to give the tag feature to the marker

```
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setText("Some Text Here");
        text.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        IconGenerator generator = new IconGenerator(context);
        generator.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.color.cyan_800_overlay));
        generator.setContentView(text);
        generator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE);
        Bitmap icon = generator.makeIcon();
        MarkerOptions tp = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(tp);
        marker.setTag(Some Tag Here);
```